# Excluding jobs in Travis.CI build matrix for non-tag builds

Tags: travis-ci

I have a normal looking Travis.CI build matrix, and I'm using deploy to Github Releases. I have one extra element in my matrix that builds and packages a source package, which I only want to build when pushing a tag.

Is there any way to skip a build in the build matrix when the build is not a tag build?

I tried something like this, but it didn't work. It still builds the source every time, which is redundant.

```
matrix:
 include:
  - os: linux
    env: DEPLOY=binary
  - os: osx
    env: DEPLOY=binary
  - os: linux
    env: DEPLOY=source
    on:
      tags: true       # <- try and skip this job for non-tag builds (doesn't work!)

[...]

deploy:
  provider: releases
  on:
    tags: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible at the moment due to a way a build matrix is created. The only solution that I can think of is to check for `TRAVIS_TAG` environment variable in jobs that you would like to skip and not run tests there. I'm aware that this has a few drawbacks as we will still create and run the build, but at least it will be fast.

Comment: super-useful reply! <3

Answer (score 1):

I know this was a long ago but for future reference, what it worked for me is: `if: tag IS present`. So you matrix would be:

```
matrix:
 include:
  - os: linux
    env: DEPLOY=binary
  - os: osx
    env: DEPLOY=binary
  - os: linux
    env: DEPLOY=source
    if: tag IS present
```